# Define a function areasq(x,y) such that when argument (x,y) is not written, the code directly assumes the value to be 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

***I want to define a function calculating area of a square/rectangle using 2 variables(x,y)***

```
def areasq(x,y):
    ara= x*y
    print("Area is :", ara)
areasq(7)
```

Is there any changes I can make such that when i'm not defining either x or y, it directly takes the value to be 1.

Comment: `def areasq(x = 1, y = 1):`
      `ara = x * y`
      `print("Area is: ", ara)`

Answer (score 1):

Use default arguments:

```
def areasq(x=1, y=1):
    ara = x * y
    print("Area is :", ara)
areasq(7)
```

Comment: depending on how else you want to use this, you may want to specify which variable you are providing. like... areasq(y=7)